# how to display the same image in dialog box when it is clicked in a html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

The code is displaying the dialog box when i am using button tag but while using image tag the dialog box is not appearing.
Can anyone please help ?

```
 <img src='image.png' height='200px' widht='200px' id='1'>

<div id="dialog" title="An Image!" >
  <img id="image" src="hello.jpg"/>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "img" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
```

Comment: I don't believe that what you are trying to achieve can be done like that. I would suggest for you to implement a custom Modal that behaves like a dialog box. Or use a ready plugin.

Comment: @N.Ivanov thankyou so much, was able to do it using custom model.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='image.png' height='200px' widht='200px' id='1'>

<div id="dialog" title="An Image!" >
  <img id="image" src="image.png"/>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
  $( "img" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
});
```